# Linq Lambda group by get max

Tags: c#, linq

I like to get the Max Sample Num for where the Id is 9

```
    var samplecount = dbContext.ChemDetails
                      .GroupBy(a => a.Id == 9)
                      .Select(a => a.Max(w => w.Sample_Num))
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

What I am getting from above is the max, not from where Id == 9.

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a `Where` clause, then take the max:

```
var maxNumber = dbContext.Where(a => a.Id == 9).Max(a => a.Sample_Num);
```

If you wanted to get the max value for each `Id`, that's when you'd use `GroupBy`.

```
Dictionary<int,int> MaxLookup = dbContext.ChemDetails
    .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Max(item => item.Sample_Num));
int maxForId9 = 0;
if (MaxLookup.ContainsKey(9)) maxForId9 = MaxLookup[9];
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation of what a GroupBy could do for him/her.

Comment: @dbaseman - if there is no ID which is equal to 9, I get an error. How can I prevent this

Comment: @WebDev just check if the key exists using `ContainsKey`.